# Displaying a Form Field Depending on Previous Question

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I develop my own template for Joomla and i need to display more options if you set a value before.

**For example:**

[image]

**after clicking on YES:**

[image]

It would be nice if in the joomla core a solution like this:

```
<field name="field1" type="radio" class="btn-group" default="0" label="Deactivate Joomla JavaScript" >
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</field>
<field name="field2" type="checkboxes" class="btn-group" default="0" label="Deactivate Joomla JavaScript" showif="field1::1">
<option value="0">Everything</option>
<option value="1">mootools-core.js</option>
<option value="2">mootools-more.js</option>
</field>
```

A new showif parameter with the value **field1::1** . **field1** is the previous field and number **1** is for value from the needed option to display this form field.

Comment: You will need to create a custom form field for this. There was an accordion module that had this feature in. If you selected K2 integration, another form field appeared allowing you to select the K2 category. I will try and find which module it was so you can see how they did it

Comment: Found it: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-showcase/19125

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feature which you require was introduced in Joomla 3.3.x. You now have the ability to use showon="show_label:1"

You can se the PR, which introduced the functionality here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3127

Comment: This is awesome, no more need for a JS solution or a custom button

Answer (score 0):

Is it on the admin side or on the front end?
Like for examaple you wanna insert one extra filed after selecting the menu item type on the admin site, this is what you need tot do:
Edit the default.xml in :/components/com_yourcomponent/views/folios/tmpl/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <metadata>
 <layout title="com_folio_folios_view_default_title" option="com_
 folio_folios_view_default_option">
  <message>
  <![CDATA[com_folio_folios_view_default_desc]]>
  </message>
 </layout>
 <fields name="request">
  <fieldset name="request">
   <field
    name="catid"
     type="category"
     extension="com_folio"
     class="inputbox"
     default=""
     label="COM_FOLIO_FIELD_CATID_LABEL"
     description="COM_FOLIO_FIELD_CATID_DESC"
     required="true"
    >
   <option value="0">JOPTION_SELECT_CATEGORY</option>
  </field>
  </fieldset>
 </fields>
</metadata>"
```

This one will insert a category selector after selecting your component from the popup window of your menu type.

Comment: This question is for the template Parameters.